# sklearn / CountVectorizer : fit then transform with different input corpus

Tags: python, input, scikit-learn, corpus, countvectorizer

I am using CountVectorizer from sklearn python lib to vectorize a **corpus from files** with `input='filename'` option to init CountVectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus1=['file_name1','file_name2',...]
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='filename')
MAT1 = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus1)
```

Then I need to use the model to transform a new **corpus but in numpy.array(['str1','str2'])**

```
corpus2 = numpy.array(['str1','str2'])
# ideally
MAT2 = count_vectorizer(input='content').transform(corpus2)
```

this can be ususaly done when CountVectorizer is initialized with `input='content'` but I don't know how I can specify a new type of input.

Any idea to do that or workaround solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround might be to write each item in your list in a separate file and then pass the list of names of files to the CountVectorizer object.

Comment: Yes or read each corpus1 files and fill an array with it to use CountVectorizer(input='content') at first
but in bouth cases it is a huge waist of time !

Answer (score 0):

You can change `count_vectorizer.input` value after training.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus1=['file_name1','file_name2',...]
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='filename')
MAT1 = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus1)

count_vectorizer.input = 'content'
corpus2 = numpy.array(['str1','str2'])
MAT2 = count_vectorizer.transform(corpus2)
```

I don't know if there are any implications of doing so, but, since it is a public attribute, I think you can change its value.